# no matches for kind "PodMonitor" in version "monitoring.gke.io/v1alpha1"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, prometheus, stackdriver

I tried to export prometheus metrics to google cloud monitoring and I tried to use this [docs](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/sidecar-to-workload-metrics) but when I run kubectl apply, I got this error "no matches for kind "PodMonitor" in version "monitoring.gke.io/v1alpha1"". and I tried to run "kubectl get apiservices |grep 'gke'", I didn't got "monitoring.gke.io/v1alpha1. Where and how I could get that CRD? because I didn't found same cases on the internet and I already enabled to google cloud monitoring on my cluster

[kubectl apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyrsu.png)

[kubectl get apiservice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po3mD.png)

[already enabled google cloud monitoring on my cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEab9.png)

pardon my english.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your cluster has Alpha features enabled. Sadly the Autopilot cluster does not support this.